# ExpressJS-Localhost not showing anything

Tags: node.js, express

This is my first time I am running ExpressJS. But the Localhost is not responding any data.[image: Waiting for localhost keeps on appearing at left bottom corner. Also showing the terminal command]

Below is the Code I have written

```js
const express=require('express');
const app=express();


app.get('/',(req,res)=>
{
    
});

app.listen(3000,()=>console.log("running at 3000 port"));
```

I have tried to change the localhost to 4000,5000.But same error.

Additional Information:
Running on Ubuntu 16.10

**Any clue of whats happening over here?**

Comment: I don't see an error.

Comment: Try writing something back like this: `res.json({ok:true});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not giving the browser anything to render. Try following the Hello World example in the docs and you might be pleasantly surprised:

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Comment: Yes you are right. That might be the issue. But the real problem was something in this line ->    app.use(express.json) . I wrote this at line 3. If I remove this line then the page is displayed else same reloading

Comment: Can you please tell meaning of this app.use(express.json) @imjared .

Answer (score 4):

I dont know if you still need an answer but i think i might have it.

I had the same issue with the 'app.use(express.json)'

when i deleted my server started working, it was because we were writing it work it actually is

'app.use(express.json())'

PD: that command works for telling EXPRESS that it has to read a json file or request...

i hope this can help you out

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to imjared's answer.. Always, response has to be sent back to the client(Browser) for any new page you create because that's what will be displayed on the browser. Adding res.send("some data") in the function will resolve the issue.